# Model not saving refresh token

Tags: django, heroku, google-calendar-api, python-social-auth

**Just trying to save the refresh token from Google OAuth 2.0 into the abstractuser profile which signed in.** It displays the refresh token and the user correctly. However when logged in the user doesn't have the refresh token stored in the model.

pipeline.py:

```
from .models import Profile
def save_token(user,*args,**kwargs):
    extra_data = user.social_auth.get(provider="google-oauth2").extra_data
    print(extra_data["refresh_token"],user)
    Profile.objects.get_or_create(
        username=user, defaults={"refresh_token": extra_data["refresh_token"]}
    )
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class Profile(AbstractUser):
    refresh_token = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
```

Now when displaying it, it comes up empty.

calendar.html:

```
{% block content %}
   
    {{user.refresh_token}}
    
    <h1>Calendar</h1>
    <button>+</button>
    <ul>
        {% for result in results %}
            <li>{{result.start.date}}{% if result.end.date %}-{% endif%}{{result.end.date}}: {{result.summary}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queryset method `get_or_create` does not update values in the model, it only creates a new object if it doesn't exist. If you're trying to update values in an **existing** object, you should use the second value that `get_or_create` returns to confirm it already exists and make the necessary updates.

So the adjustment would look like this:

```
def save_token(user,*args,**kwargs):
    extra_data = user.social_auth.get(provider="google-oauth2").extra_data

    profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(
        username=user, defaults={"refresh_token": 
        extra_data["refresh_token"]}
    )

    # `created` will be false if the object exists

    if not created:
        profile.refresh_token = extra_data["refresh_token"]
        profile.save()
```